# Combine two lists of strings of time zones

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, .net-core

I have a problem, i need to compare two TimeZOnes, one from data base and other from our system, i managed to compare both lists and create two lists of strings with only names of time zones but can´t create another lists with only the names that are equals from both lists

```
List<TimeZoneInfo> timeZonesInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList();

        ApiResponse<TimeZoneDTO> listOfTimeZonesFromSystem = new ApiResponse<TimeZoneDTO>();
        TimeZoneDTO Obin = new TimeZoneDTO();
        OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[1];
        param[0] = GetOracleParameter("cv_timeZone", null, OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);

        DataTable result = ExecuteDataTable(SP_Constants.GETTIMEZONE_SP, param);

        listOfTimeZonesFromSystem.Response = Obin.TransformToTimeZoneDTO(result);

        List<string> listStringsTimeZonesInfo = timeZonesInfo.ConvertAll(x => x.DisplayName.ToUpper()).ToList();
        List<string> listStringsFromSystem = listOfTimeZonesFromSystem.Response.ConvertAll(x => x.TimeZoneName.ToUpper()).ToList();

        var b = listStringsFromSystem.Any(listStringsFromSystem.Contains);

        var equals = new List<string>();

        if (b)
        {
            equals.AddRange(listStringsFromSystem.Concat(listStringsTimeZonesInfo.Contains));

        }
```

I´m getting rror CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'IEnumerable'

Comment: `listStringsFromSystem.Concat(listStringsTimeZonesInfo.Contains)` what should that do? Concat requires a list as argument, you're giving it a method. Maybe you meant `listStringsFromSystem.Concat(listStringsTimeZonesInfo))`, but that would add all timezones of both lists, not only those that match.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the intersection of both lists.
Linq provides a method to get the intersection of two IEnumerables.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect

```
var equals = listStringsTimeZonesInfo.Intersect(listStringsFromSystem).ToList();
```

Depending on what you want to do with the result, you might be able to omit
`ToList()`.

Comment: I didn´t get an error but result of list is 0

Answer (score 0):

I couldn´t do it but did another way... My main objective was convert the time zones from ou DB to GMT but i had to have the id from .NET to use TimeZoneInfo, then convert to UTC then convert to GMT, so what i did was do it one by one, get from DB compare to what came from TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList()
then do the process... thanks all and sorry my english...

Comment: Please edit to add piece of code to make this answer clearer, thanks!

Comment: `UTC` and `GMT` is (more or less) the same. `UTC` is actually the new name of `GMT`.